# Binding custom class to listbox from custom class

Tags: windows-phone-7, data-binding, binding, windows-phone-7.1

I have these classes:

```
public class MovieExt
{
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public List<string> Genres { get; set; }
        public List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
        ....
}

public class Actor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Birth { get; set; }
    public string Biography { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }

}
```

and this is my method in my page:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{

    object obj;
    if (PhoneApplicationService.Current.State.TryGetValue("movie", out obj))
    {
        MovieExt movie = (MovieExt)obj;
        this.DataContext = movie;
        this.imgPoster.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(movie.PosterUrl, UriKind.Absolute));
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

and in page I am binding properties like this:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" 
                             Margin="5,5,5,5"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Actors }"
                             x:Name="listStars"/>
```

For everything it´s working (genres and others). Everything else is string. But for actors I want to bind in list name and after clicking on the actor I want to go to url. How can I bind name property from actor? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to create `OnSelectedItemChanged` event on your `ListBox` to handle clicks on your `Actors`.

Then you need to get your clicked item. You can do this in several ways. The simplest way is `listBox.SelectedItem` property.

And then your can get your Url with `(listBox.SelectedItem as Actor).Url`

Also, when you go back from details page, `SelectedItem` will be not null and click on the same item not fired event in second time. So, set `SelectedItem` to null when click is handled

**UPD**: to properly bind `Actor` class to `ListBox` you need to create `ItemTemplate`:

```
 <ListBox ...>
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                     <TextBlock Text={Binding Name} />
                     <TextBlock Text={Binding Birth} />
                     <TextBlock Text={Binding Biography} />
                     <TextBlock Text={Binding Url} />
                </StackPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: It´s for handle clicks and it´s great, thansk for this. But it´s not my problem. I want to show name property from actor class in listbox but now I have "namespace.Actor".

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `ToString()` method in the Actor class to display something friendly, like the name.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
```

This is useful when binding objects to comboboxes and dropdowns.

Comment: Why was this downrated? Care to elaborate?

Comment: It wasn´t by me, I think your answer is smart but I think I´ll use itemtemplate.

Comment: I would use ItemTemplate as well as it is more versatile, but many times I found myself only needing to change the way the item text is displayed and overriding ToString is the way to go in those cases, which is why I suggested it.